# can't access 127.0.0.1:80 outside of WSL2 / Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, hyper-v, ubuntu-20.04, wsl2

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2 / Hyper-V / Windows 10.

When I do `curl http://127.0.0.1` inside Ubuntu I get this back:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.19.3</center>
</body>
</html>
```

When I do it on the host - on Windows 10 itself (with Git Bash) I get this:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
```

How can I make port 80 accessible outside of Ubuntu? Do I need to update the firewall rules in Windows or something?

Comment: What are the results of `ifconfig` within WSL2 and `ipconfig` within Windows? As far as I know WSL is essentially a very lightweight virtual machine so a similar access method through the virtual network card should apply. Essentially you need the actual machine address as per the answer from Mark, and to ensure that firewalls are suitably permissive.

Comment: If none of the suggestions work, check if C:\program files\wsl\wslrelay.exe is allowed to access the network. I was using a third-party firewall, and it blocked wslrelay.exe. Just like you, I was able to access the port inside WSL2 but not from the outside.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because each host has a localhost 127.0.0.1. The windows host thinks it's going to itself.  The easiest solution is for you to IP with a real IP. example 192.168.x.x

I found the following blurb

In the early stages of WSL 2, we can’t use localhost. We need to use an IP since Linux is inside a VM.

To access your application currently, we will use an IP.

Comment: “I found the following blurb” - Please cite your source

Comment: Doing `ifconfig` on Ubuntu to get the IP address (192.168.207.172) and then updating my Windows hosts file to use it seems to do the trick. Altho it is a bit annoying...  what if the IP address changes? Having to update my hosts file every time I get a new IP address is a bit of a PITA

Comment: @neubert Use a scheduled task: https://abdus.dev/posts/fixing-wsl2-localhost-access-issue/

Answer (score 28):

#### Problem:

Windows 10 thinks localhost is `::1`.

```
PS C:\Users\michael> ping localhost

Pinging DESKTOP[::1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
```

Ubuntu thinks localhost is `127.0.0.1`

```
$ ~ > cat /etc/hosts
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateHosts = false
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       DESKTOP.localdomain     DESKTOP
```

#### Current Solution: 5/31/2022

I haven't been having this problem recently.  I think I've done "Network Reset" once in the last 4 months.

#### 'Network Reset' Solution: 7/27/2021

WSL is changing relatively quickly.

My current solution w/ WSL2 is

1. "Start->Network Reset (system settings)->Reset
2. Casually reboot windows like it's 1998.
3. Get on with my life.

#### Solution 1:

1. Read [this documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config)
2. Notice the obscure note in wsl settings about true except for some builds.
3. Add a file with these contents to `C:\Users\Me\.wslconfig`, or, respectively, `C:\Users\%UserProfile%\.wslconfig`:

```
[wsl2]
localhostForwarding=true
```

This is what worked for me.

#### Solution 2:

This didn't work so well for me, but might for you.  Stop automatic generation as instructed in the comments in `/etc/hosts`, and change localhost to `::1` so they refer to the same adapter.  For compatibility, `0.0.0.0` binds to all interfaces (127.0.0.1 and ::1) so it works.

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateHosts = false
127.0.0.1       ip4-localhost
::1 localhost

...
```

Will this mess things up?  Probably.  If it does, you'll have to remember to fiddle this to get that to work.

Comment: OP should mark this as the correct solution, the `localhostForwarding` config did the trick for me. Now I don't have to open up VSCode every time I want to start a dev server (for some reason clicking the localhost URL output from VSCode's terminal worked, but it wouldn't work if I manually typed it into the browser). Now all is working as expected, thanks!

Comment: This worked out of all hundred solutions over the internet +1

Comment: @Md.AbuTaher There are two solutions in Michael Cole's answer. Which one worked for you?

Comment: @luisdev I updated the answer to what I'm doing now.

Comment: By far the most simplest and effective answer at the time I'm writing this (Jan. 1, 2021). Great work, thank you! This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: FYI as of now `localhostForwarding = true` is the default

Answer (score 13):

This is what worked for me, as with localhost/127.0.0.1 I had no luck:

1. get WSL2 linux IP using ifconfig:

> ```
> aristos32@DESKTOP-V493N00:~$ ifconfig
> eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>         inet 172.21.115.144  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.21.127.255
>         inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fea0:1a98  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
> ```

2. use this IP in the browser instead of localhost

> `http://172.21.115.144/`

Comment: My problem is that IP changes every time you restart the computer. I need an IP that never (or seldom) changes (or access to localhost in Ubuntu WSL).

Comment: @luisdev Use a scheduled task to update the IP: https://abdus.dev/posts/fixing-wsl2-localhost-access-issue/

Answer (score 5):

You can either use the IPv6 address for localhost in Windows [http://[::1]/](http://%5B::1%5D/) or [http://localhost](http://localhost/).
Both work for me with Windows 11 and WSL2.

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already have well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.

Comment: This was the most relevant answer for me as of 2022.

Answer (score 4):

My solution was adding both 127.0.0.1 and ::1 for the local domain to the Windows host file.

```
127.0.0.1       mydomain.local
::1             mydomain.local
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2 / Windows 10
and running my backend(nodejs + koa) on ubuntu (localhost) and make request using postman from windows.

using the url `http://127.0.0.1:port` I could not access my server

looks funny but it worked for me to simply change the url (on postman) `http://127.0.0.1:port` to `http://localhost:port`

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  I'd recommend reading through the existing answers before adding a new answer.  This solution seems to be identical to [this one](https://superuser.com/a/1750410/1210833) that was posted less than a month ago.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

date: 2023Feb.
Wha I am using: windows 10 with VSCode WSL2.
What worked for me?
Disabling the IP Helper service resolved it. Go to servcies.msc>disable it or set it to manual.
You may also check the resource monitor tool in windows which shows the ports that are being used by the app.
Source of my solution:
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5575

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: Do NOT disable IPv6 on WSL2

Running 22.04 WSL2 Windows 10 - Same issues as reported above.

All the advice and tips I could find on the internet regarding this issue couldn't help me. Then a loose reference to IPv6 made me think.

In an attempt to fix a completely separate issue, I had taken some advice to disable IPv6 for WSL2 by adding

```
kernelCommandLine=ipv6.disable=1
```

into C:\Users\MYUSER.wslconfig

This indeed stops IPv6 inside WSL2 ... but it now turns out that this was responsible for killing my localhost access to WSL2 from Windows.

Re-enabling IPv6 for WSL2 got it all going again.

I am assuming Windows is trying to use the IPv6 ::1 localhost channel to get to WSL2 ?!?!?

... Just something else for you to consider in trying to resolve this problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

Restart the apache2 service:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```